# How to get custom NSManagedObject subclass from selected UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, delegation

I have a UITableView in my app that displays some Location objects which I have created as part of a Core Data store. The UITableViewCell actually just displays the name of the Location (one of the properties on the Location object). When the user selects a Location, I want to use delegation to pass the Location object to the previous view controller, not just the text that's in the cell.

I am trying to think of the best way to do this and can create a new Location object to pass back, but don't know how I would get the actual object who's text was being displayed in the UITableViewCell.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [NSFetchedResultsController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html). It is meant to do exactly what you want: displaying Core Data objects in a table view.

Comment: Thanks very much. I was using a FetchedResultsController to display the cells but didn't think of it for the selection. I did :     Location *selectedLocation = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]; and it works great.

Answer (score 1):

If you have populated your `TableView` with an array (like from a `FetchRequest`), then using

```
MyManagedObjectSubclass *selectedManagedObject = [myDataSourceArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` delegate method will get you what you need.